# Alternatives to django-guardian get_objects_for_user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-guardian

We are successfully using django-guardian and django-rest-framework on a project. However, the standard way to get objects for a certain user with certain permissions seems very slow when the user has 1000's of objects with the required permissions set.

It produces a query with 1000s of IDs in an `IN` clause. This seems to have a subsequent effect when taking into account network latency between web server and database server: extracting 1000s of ids from the database, parsing them, then sending them back to the database in the `IN` clause.

Are there any documented workarounds for this? Hacking around with the `get_objects_for_user` method and changing the `object_pk` column to an integer, I was able to get it running with an inline select statement:

```
select ... from my_table where ... and id in (select id from guardian...
```

vs the current statements of:

```
select id from guardian_userobjectpermissions where ...
... generate list of ids in python ...
select ... from my_table where ... and id in ([big list of ids])
```

A further workaround I have not tried yet is to somehow reduce the scope of ids fetched by guardian. e.g. a user has 1000's of objects, but I'm only interested in objects from the past 6 months. At the moment, it fetches all possible object ids with the correct permissions for the user rather than restricting it in any way.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help, but I just hit the same problem. See https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/issues/189 especially the analysis from cancan101 https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/issues/189#issuecomment-59443689

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted over two years ago and you have most likely resolved this problem one way or another, but I have just hit the same problem and came up with this question in my search. I do not have a pure ORM solution, but if you are willing to use raw SQL, you can do this pretty efficiently. The SQL looks like this

```
SELECT
    obj.*
FROM guardian_userobjectpermission as op
JOIN auth_user as u ON (op.user_id = u.id)
JOIN auth_permission as p ON (op.permission_id = p.id)
JOIN django_content_type as ct ON (ct.id = op.content_type_id)
JOIN myapp_mymodel as obj ON (obj.id = op.object_pk::integer)
WHERE u.id = user_id AND p.codename = 'mymodel_perm' AND ct.model = 'mymodel' AND ct.app_label = 'myapp'
```

where a model named MyModel lives in an app called myapp, has a permission called mymodel_perm and user_id is the primary key of the user you are looking up objects for.